# systemd service fails to use `tail` to output to console

Tags: systemd-unit, systemd-mount

I fail to configure my systemd service properly (systemd 249.11-0ubuntu3.12). It should start a `tail` process which outputs to the console. Ubuntu running as Proxmox VM.

When booting, the service is started but exits without helpful output:

```
× watchbackup.service - Startup Applications
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/watchbackup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-03-01 21:47:01 CET; 27s ago
    Process: 939 ExecStart=/opt/backup-proxmox/tools/watchbackup.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 939 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

If I restart the service *manually*, it works as intended. The execed shell script (I failed miserably to put the `tail` directly to the service unit file's `ExecStart` command):

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 5
ls -la  /net/var/archiv-1/log/ > /tmp/foo
echo tty1 > /dev/tty1
echo tty0 > /dev/tty0
echo console > /dev/console
tail -f /net/var/archiv-1/log/backup.log
```

The sleep succeeds to delay, the file exists as expected (although `/net/var/archiv-1` is an NFS mount), all three echoes are visible on the console. However, `tail` terminates immediately.

My last attempt service unit file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Startup Applications
After=network.target
After=net-var-archiv\x2d1.mount
After=net-var-archiv\x2d1.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/backup-proxmox
ExecStart=/opt/backup-proxmox/tools/watchbackup.sh
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Type=simple
StandardOutput=tty
StandardError=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any suggestions to identify the reason why I cannot `tail` the file if the service is started at boot time but I can when restarting the service manually?

Comment: Does the `tail` work manually?  I.e. what happens when you issue `tail -f /net/var/archiv-1/log/backup.log` in a terminal?

Comment: @eyoung100: Yes, it works manually. From ssh session or tty1 console, both work as expected and follow the file. When the service is manually restarted right after booting (`ssh archiv-1 systemctl restart watchbackup.service`), it works as well, the file content is shown on tty1.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the Native SystemD Journal

Replace `tail` with `journalctl -f -u watchbackup.service`

I can't find out why tail isn't allowed, only the fix.  I'll add a more fleshed out answer when I can find why, but I suspect it has something to do with the fact that tail cannot monitor a real time write, and systemd being the init system is running in real-time.

Comment: That's weird. This doesn't work as well, the service terminates as well when using journalctl.

Comment: does `journalctl` contain any info related to the failure?